# Adding an attribute to Class Meta of Built in model

Tags: python, django, authentication

Can I add an attribute to Class Meta of auth.User model of django without extending the model ?

Comment: No. But why don't you want to extend the model?

Comment: I already have a model which has OnetoOne relation with User model.

Comment: It's not like you can't use both. In fact, I'd recommend to always extend the user model, even if you don't do anything different from the default user model. Without one, changing anything will be a huge effort.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. But extending shouldn't be a problem unless you have to deal with a lot of references to Django's User model.

[Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: Ok. what if I have a CustomUser model with onetoone relation with auth.user ?

Comment: You will extend and override the default User and use Django's generic methods to reference the new model in models.py. Inside models.py you will point to AUTH_USER_MODEL instead of auth.user directly. Everything is described in the documentation.